# How to use foreach for array

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I am trying to display "name" object, but its not working. I seem to be using foreach wrong.. I print_r for $a and it displays the array. Can someone help.

```
public function product(){
        $st = $this->db->prepare("select id, name, description, price from deals where quantity > 0 order by id desc");
        $st->execute();

        if ($st->rowCount() == 0){
            echo "There are no products to display";
        } else {
            $a = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ)

            foreach ($a as $products){
                echo $products->name;
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you need a foreach loop for what you are doing.

```
while( $products = $st->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) )
{
    echo $products->name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

fetch() only returns one row.  Your foreach is looping through all the properties of the object returned by fetch(), i.e. the column names.